# Call functions from data segment

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I would like to do a reverse engineering analysis of the "xormadness.exe" executable file from root-me.org (PE x86 format), but i don't understand why functions are called from the data segment and how do we know which function is called.

```
.text:0040105e ff 15 0c 20 40 00                call   DWORD PTR ds:0x40200c
```

Here, i can see that a function call is done, but i don't understand why the data segment is used.

```
.rdata:0040200c 80                               0x80
```

Furthermore, this address have nothing to do with a function, there is only a 0x80 byte value and i don't understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an indirect function call as evidenced by the `DWORD PTR` token sequence.  The function address is fetched from a dword at address `0x40200c` and then a call is performed to that function.

The `ds:` segment prefix is a red herring.  This is just what segment a directly addressed memory operand defaults to.  As you are probably programming for a flat memory model, you can ignore this.